SMS/Email/TOTP/Hardware keys, which one?
When you’re setting up MFA for an app, system, or workflow, how do you decide what method to use—SMS, email, TOTP, or hardware keys? Do you stick to one across the board, or pick based on the situation, like testing environments vs. production, or regular users vs. admins? I’d love to hear how your team approaches this and where you draw the line between security, usability, and practicality.
I am trying to decide between the different methodologies to know which is the best for my use case.
